# Is it possible to add shortcut key to button in app?

Tags: android

I wrote an application with the multiple screens, one of the screen is LoginScreen containing two TextView's two EditText's & two Buttons,

my question is, is it possible to add a shortcut key for Button when you device has hard keyboard present.

Best Regards,
Anup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `onKeyListener` to your `Activity` and use it to simulate a click event on the button ( `button.performClick();` )

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html
and here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but lets say I have a login button & I want to assign shift+s as a hard  keyboardshortcut then how do I proceed

Comment: Read the API how to implement a KeyListener here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html and the keycodes here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#META_SHIFT_ON . There you have everything you need to do it.